# Styling a nested styled-component from an outer one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, inline-styles

Using styled-components, I am trying to style a nested `<Input />` component that I have created, which is being used within a different component that has a dropdown appear when typing. I need to add `padding-left: 3rem` to this nested input but I cannot access it from the component `<Dropdown />`.

```
<Dropdown
  options={options}
/>
```

The above is imported where I need it. I need to access the below input from the above `<Dropdown />`.

```
<div>
  <Input {...props}/> // I need to edit the padding in this component
  // rendered input unique to this new component would go here
</div>
```

The above `<Input />` is imported from another component which is used in all instances where I require an input.

```
export const Dropdown = styled(DropDown)`
  padding-left: 3rem !important;
`;
```

The component works fine but this fails to affect the inner padding of the Input that I need to target.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said, I'd suggest that the dependency of padding the `Input` component is with your `Dropdown` (which you seem to realise already).

Therefore you'd be better off having that "unqiue" styling coupled with your `Dropdown` component via a wrapping styled component within it.

The following example is crude (and by no means complete or working), but hopefully it illustrates how the ownership of the `padding-left` should be within the `Dropdown` and not a sporadic styled component floating some where else in your code base.

./Input/Input.jsx

```
const Input = ({ value }) => (
  <input value={value} />
);
```

./Dropdown/styled.js

```
const InputWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3rem !important; /* Your padding */
`;

const Icon = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: blue;
`;

const Menu = styled.ul`/* whatever */`;
```

./Dropdown/Dropdown.jsx

```
import Input from '...';
import { InputWrapper, Icon, Menu } from './styled';
const Dropdown = ({ options }) => (
  <div>
    <InputWrapper>
      <Icon />
      <Input value={'bleh'} />
    </InputWrapper>
    <Menu>{options}</Menu>
  </div>
);
```

This setup will promote reusable `self-contained` components.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution below:

```
export const StyledInput = styled.div`
  && #id-for-input { // specifically on the <Input />
    padding-left: 3rem !important;
  }
`;


<StyledInput>
  <Dropdown />
</StyledInput>
```

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't look as trivial as it should be.  Normally, nested components not getting styled correctly is due to not having className being passed through from the parent.  Can you post the source of dropdown and input

Comment: And do you want the padding on the Input or the Dropdown?

Comment: @andymccullough I only wanted padding within the input, I had an icon there and wanted to shift the starting point for the placeholder/text

there are a lot of dependencies for the Dropdown, that's why I kept it simple in the example